# Want to know if I may apply for the patent or not

Tags: inventorship

I have made one inspire-able  sentence which is very helpful in living life for inspiration, because with the help of inspiration everything is possible. So shall I apply and get the patent for that sentence which I made.  If yes tell me procedure abut that, hope you do for needful.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. Patents are for inventions. An inspirational sentence is not an invention and would be rejected as being wholly abstract and also under the printed material doctrine.

Answer (score 4):

A sentence cannot be patented. It can be protected under copyrights.

A patent is granted to an invention which has new and inventive solution to a technical problem.

You may want to refer the article at the below link to get insight on what can be patented and what cannot be patented:
http://www.invntree.com/blogs/what-can-be-patented-and-what-cannot-be-patented

Answer (score 2):

You cannot patent a sentence. Here are the list of ideas or innovations that cannot be patented.

- Laws of nature
- Physical phenomena
- Abstract ideas Literary, dramatic, musical, and artistic works (these can be Copyright protected)
- Inventions which are: 
   Not useful (such as perpetual motion machines); or Offensive to public morality

Comment: I'm not sure what "physical phenomena" is intended to mean but would add "abstract idea without something more". It sounds ridiculous but is from a recent Supreme Court opinion. Offensive to public order is a real reason for rejection in Europe, but not in the U.S. Design patents *can* get rejected for offensive images but it is under "all business with the patent office must be conducted with decorum" so it doesn't have a real foundation.